# TabBar selected indicator doesn't display correctly

Tags: flutter, mobile-application

So, I had the code working well, then all of a sudden, I came back to it, and the TabBar doesn't fill the entire screen and shows a small circle indicating that that tab has been selected.

This is how it displays, instead of that inner circle to fill it's parent.

[image]

This is the code:

```
 DefaultTabController(
   length: 2,
   child: Column(
       children: <Widget>[
           Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.w),
              width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
              color: AppColor.grey3,
            ),
              child: TabBar(
                splashBorderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                indicator: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                color: AppColor.white2,
              ),
                unselectedLabelStyle: AppStyle.body1,
                labelColor: AppColor.primaryDark,
                labelStyle: AppStyle.body1,
                tabs: const [
                    Tab(text: 'Active'),
                    Tab(text: 'Past'),
               ],
             ),
         )
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab` to the TabBar, will fix the issue